# Macro to Insert Row after Certain text

Tags: text, macros, insert, row

all.
I found in a previous post, a solution that solved most of my problem.  I just need some help expanding on it a little.  The following macro was posted (and I have amended it for my application) to add a row after the text "CC Total" appeared.  I need this macro to add a row after "CC Total" and the text "Sum Total".  how can I add this second criteria to the command?

```html
 Dim Col As Variant
    Dim BlankRows As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim StartRow As Long

        Col = "A"
        StartRow = 1
        BlankRows = 1

            LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False

            With ActiveSheet
    For R = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
    If .Cells(R, Col) = "CC Total" Then
    .Cells(R + 1, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
    End If
    Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Thanks.  How difficult is it to make the command insert more than 1 row?

Answer (score 0):

The following line is key here:

```
If .Cells(R, Col) = "CC Total" Then
```

To add extra criteria, you can either do

```
If .Cells(R, Col) = "CC Total" Or .Cells(R, Col) = "SUM Total" Then
```

or, to make it more accessible for more criteria:

```
If .Cells(R, Col) = "CC Total" Then
    ....
ElseIf .Cells(R, Col) = "SUM Total" Then
    ....
etc
End if
```

Comment: The first suggestion worked, but the second did not.  it added the row after the "sum total" but didn't add it after the "cc total".  Is there something I should use instead of ElseIF?  I will use the first suggestions, I was just wandering about the second for future reference.  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, have you debugged your code and/or looped it through until you encountered a "CC Total"? Also, check the [if..then..else](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs(v=vs.90).aspx) statement syntax to rule out any typos.